# What culture does the javascript Date object use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The language of my OS (Windows) is in danish, and so is the language of my browsers.

When i am trying to parse a Date in the danish format (dd-MM-yyyy) like this:

```
var x = "18-08-1989"
var date = new Date(x);
```

I get the wrong date from javascript (i want 18'th of August 1989). When i transform this string to english, and parse it, it returns the correct date.

Does the format of the date string always have to be: yyyy-MM-dd when using the JS Date object??

Comment: "18-08-89" is not in the "dd-MM-yyyy" format, have you tried "18-08-1989"?

Comment: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: I corrected my question, and yes I have tried it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In basic use without specifying a locale, a formatted string in the default locale and with default options is returned.

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 12, 3, 0, 0));

// toLocaleString without arguments depends on the implementation,
// the default locale, and the default time zone
date.toLocaleString();
// "12/11/2012, 7:00:00 PM" if run in en-US locale with time zone America/Los_Angeles
```

**Using locales**

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

// formats below assume the local time zone of the locale;
// America/Los_Angeles for the US

// US English uses month-day-year order
alert(date.toLocaleString("en-US"));
// "12/19/2012, 7:00:00 PM"

// British English uses day-month-year order
alert(date.toLocaleString("en-GB"));
// "20/12/2012 03:00:00"

// Korean uses year-month-day order
alert(date.toLocaleString("ko-KR"));
// "2012. 12. 20. 오후 12:00:00"
```

Comment: Do you have an idea why the default locale is english when my browser and OS is in danish ? :)

Comment: @Kenci Dates don't do locale dependent parsing, they only accept strings in one of two formats. Take a look at the [MDN entry for Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: @DavidHedlund I think we have very different ideas about what the question is asking, then, because I've downvoted for not answering it at all. They're asking about parsing strings to create Date objects, which this doesn't address.

Comment: What i am asking is how to tell javascript that my date string is in danish and have it automatically parse it correctly and create a valid Date object from the string?

Comment: @Kenci You can't with regular JavaScript, you'll have to manually split your string into the component parts (day, month, and year) then create a new string in the ISO 8601 format to pass to the constructor. You *might* be able to do it with [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) but I can't say for sure because I've never used it (I usually work with dates server-side).

Answer (score 1):

Look here form more info about Date object:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

And here about format:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14